# How to pass multiple where clause variables to bind_param?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to do a multi query using prepared statements.
I am getting number of bind param errors :

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in C:\wamp\www\c\index.php on line 35
```

Line 35 is:

```
$stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
```

Here is total codes:
I tried several examples but couldnt make it work.

Example 1:
    `$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);` //output id from session
Example 2:

```
$stmt->bind_param('ii',$id, $user_id);
```

And some more tries too.

`$id = $_SESSION['id'];` // value comes from session and its full

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT users.*, stores.*, products.* FROM stores, products, users WHERE users.id = ? AND stores.user_id = ? AND products.user_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $user_id, $pname);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
echo $pname;
```

When I do queries in phpmyadmin codes works fine on $sql as following 2 queries:

```
$sql = "SELECT users.*, stores.*, products.*\n"

    . "FROM stores, products, users\n"

    . "WHERE ((users.id) AND (stores.user_id) AND (products.user_id))";
```

AND without php code

```
SELECT users.*, stores.*, products.* 
FROM stores, products, users 
WHERE ((users.id) 
AND (stores.user_id) 
AND (products.user_id))
```

This is the closest example :
I am having error:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in C:\wamp\www\c\index.php on line 37
```

Line 37 is :

```
$stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $pname);

$id = $_SESSION['id'];
```

Closest code :

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT users.*, stores.*, products.* FROM stores, products, users WHERE users.id = stores.user_id AND stores.user_id = products.user_id AND products.user_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $pname);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
echo $pname;
```

Comment: Shouldn't `$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);` be `$stmt->bind_param('?', $id);` or `$stmt->bind_param(1, $id);`. Why are you binding to 'i'?

Comment: I tried that too but having error : Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Undefined fieldtype 1 (parameter 2) in C:\wamp\www\c\index.php on line 35 same line

Comment: My mistake, thought you were using `PDO`.

Answer (score 1):

Your prepared statement contains 3 questionmarks/placeholder. So you have to bind exactly 3 values.

I think this should work:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT users.*, stores.*, products.* FROM stores, products, users WHERE users.id = ? AND stores.user_id = ? AND products.user_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('iii', $user_id, $user_id, $user_id);
```

See examples at: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Should I change select all to SELECT to columns FROM ?

Comment: @kaanavşar no. When using `bind_param` you need to use pass the exact same number of parameters to `bind_param` as placeholders you have set e.g. `WHERE x = ? AND y = ? AND z = ?`, you can't do `bind_param('i', $x);`. You need to do `bind_param('iii', $x, $y, $z)`.

Comment: Yes I do that Like so :` $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT users.id, users.username, stores.user_id, stores.name, products.user_id, products.pname FROM stores, products, users WHERE users.id = ? AND stores.user_id = ? AND products.user_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('iii', $id, $user_id, $user_id);` this the right way, I have tried it before too. still having, bind_param-> get_result; variables problem  @Script47

Comment: in this instance, why not just do `users.id = ? AND stores.user_id = users.id AND products.user_id = users.id` then you only need to bind the one id param, since this would be an implicit *[INNER JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50204156/how-to-pass-multiple-where-clause-variables-to-bind-param) and , (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of a join condition*.

Comment: I will try it now and see what I do! isnt that variables are  mysqli oop ? @fyrye

Comment: @kaanavşar if you choose to leave the  3 parameter placeholders (`?`), you would want to do `$stmt->bind_param('iii', $id, $id, $id);` So that the `?` becomes the specified values of `$id` in the order they were declared (bound). Also order of operations would make my previous statement need to be `stores.user_id = ? AND products.user_id = stores.user_id AND users.id = stores.user_id` since you select from `stores` first.

Comment: check my working code example in my own answer please , I couldnt make INNER JOIN AND LEFT JOIN work. @fyrye

Answer (score 0):

Here is working sample of the code, I had to change:

```
SELECT users.*, stores.*, products.* FROM
```

To

```
SELECT users.id, users.username, stores.user_id, stores.name, products.user_id, products.pname FROM
```

And rest of the code like so: and its working now, I wouldlike to know if its safe to use on a live and dynamic website ?

Can someone correct the code please.
Here is total working code

```
    $id = $_SESSION['UserId'];
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT users.id, users.username, stores.user_id, stores.name, products.user_id, products.pname 
     FROM stores, products, users 
     WHERE users.id = ? 
     AND stores.user_id = users.id 
     AND products.user_id = users.id");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $username, $user_id, $name, $user_id, $pname);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
    echo $pname;

    echo"<br>" .$name;

    echo "<br>".$username;
```

I tried INNER JOIN AND LEFT JOIN (Mentioned in comment) but couldnt made both. work

```
EDİT :
```

Same query with INNER JOIN its working.

```
$sid = $_SESSION['UserId'];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT u.id, u.username, s.user_id, s.name, p.user_id, p.pname FROM stores AS s INNER JOIN products AS p ON p.store_id = s.store_id INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id = p.user_id WHERE s.user_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $sid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $username, $user_id, $name, $user_id, $pname);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
echo $pname;

echo"<br>" .$name;

echo "<br>".$username;
```

Comment: The explicit inner join (the equivalent of `FROM t1, t2, t3`) would be written like `SELECT *
FROM stores AS s
INNER JOIN products AS p
ON p.store_id = s.id
INNER JOIN users AS u
ON u.id = s.user_id
WHERE s.user_id = ?` See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06418a/2 for an example. `LEFT JOIN`  would cause any tables that don't match the specified criteria to be NULL (e.g. if the products or users does not exist.)

Comment: it works on phpmyadmin query but when add it to my code then I am having Error in  `$stmt->bind_result($id, $user_id, $user_id, $store_id, $username, $name, $pname);`Error I am having with variables, Do I have to add all values in 3 tables to bind_result ? `Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result():  Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in C:\wamp\www\c\index.php on line 3`

Comment: In short, yes you should. It is recommended to explicitly select any of the columns you want to `bind_result` to variables, without repeating variable names. eg. `SELECT u.id, u.username, s.name, p.pname` then `bind_result($user_id, $user_name, $store_name, $product_name)` That way if you add columns to your tables, you do not break your PHP code, since `*` would return an additional column that was not programmed.

Comment: No worries, keep at it and keep improving. I suggest switching from `mysqli` to `PDO` as it is a lot more portable (in case you ever need to query a MSSQL or SqLite database) and easier to read IMHO. No more needing to `bind_param`, `bind_result` though still optional Allowing you to work with named parameters (instead of ?), and the addition of `fetchColumn` as well as being able to fetch directly into an object make it extremely useful in comparison..

Comment: why use INNER JOIN ifyour query is working without more codes ? I bet first example will be more usable and faster.

Comment: @ErcanKoç `SELECT * FROM t1, t2` is the short syntax for the explicit inner join and is the same as writing: `SELECT * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2`. The short syntax will operate with the same performance as the explicit but is much harder to read and determine how the joins are operating, as the criteria is in the `WHERE` clause of the query, rather than explicitly defined in the `JOIN ON`. e.g `WHERE t2.user = t1.user AND t1.id = t2.t1_id, AND t3.id = t2.t3_id AND t1.user = 1` How are the tables being joined from t2 and t3 on to t1?